The application Silhouette can't be opened, Is there any solution
The application Silhouette can't be opened, Is there any solution, Software BorisFx Silhouette 2023
I tried terminal command chmod +x.. but that didn't worked for me, I tried to install gain and added entry in firewall , still have the problem not working.
